# Running a hibernate constraint individually?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

Is it possible to check a String against a hibernate constraint without having to write a special Class for it? For example, if I just want to check if a given String is an email, is it possible to check it as a one-off test without writing a full class and validating that constraint against a particular property of the class?

Comment: Look into `org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.EmailValidator`, which I think does the email validation.

Answer (score 6):

You  can annotate the property with @Email in your entity class. You can read the documentation in this link: http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/Email.html

**Edited:**

```
String email = "email@test.com";
EmailValidator validator = new EmailValidator();
validator.isValid(email, null);
```

The method "isValid" will return true if your string is a well-formed email address.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know I can do that, this question is about how to run those constraints on a string without having to validate it against an entity class.

Comment: Mind you though, that by doing so you are instantiating implementation classes of Hibernate Validator which you should not do, unless you are aware that this is neither a portable solution nor something one can rely on.  It might be ok for some ad hoc testing, but I would not do this in production code.

Comment: @Hardy what would be the best way to obtain the `EmailValidator` instance then? There are cases when we need to validate list of emails and for this we need `EmailValidator `.

Comment: It is fine to use the EmailValidator like this. It is just that we give no guarantee regarding backwards API stability for internal classes. For public API and SPI we attempt to not break existing contracts or at least provide a migration path. Internal classes we might change without a migration path and without any warning.